# Getting discord webhook from site

Tags: javascript, php, discord, phishing

Is there a way to get a Discord webhook from a site? I know of a phishing site that prompts you for your name and password, which it then sends to a Discord server. Last time they were using JavaScript for the webhook so it was easy to find it and delete. Now they are using PHP. Is it possible to find the webhook?

Comment: No, you can not just get what webhook URLs other apps might use - the webhook is server-side. But the point of your question is not very clear; why would _you_ need to "find and delete" another site's webhook, even if it was a phishing site?

Comment: It's impossible if they're sending data to the webhook on the server side. The only way to find the webhook in that case is getting access to source code. But this probably impossible.